# A way to accept a network connection while running other tasks?

Tags: c, multithreading, daemon

I am building a server application that is supposed to do text processing in the background but it's task changes based on signals from a client application. My problem is that I can't do the programs primary job while waiting for connections. Is there anyway to run this job at the same time? I have looked at multithreading, however because the application is supposed to maintain an internal state while running I can't work out how make it function in this way. The program is written in C.

Comment: `however because the application is supposed to maintain an internal state while running I can't work out how make it function in this way` Could you please be more concrete about why you cant multithreading? Multithreading is actually what your asking for: It means running two code branches (threads) concurrently. Your problem might be solved with synchronization (e.g a mutex). These are commonly used constructs if working with multithreading. Multithreading itself just becomes complex if multiple threads have to communicate and depend on each other.

Comment: Split the job into chunks -- then yield to the main loop every few millis of processing. Unless it's really, really hard to split the workload into chunks, multithreading is just too hard. To be honest, the question is very broad -- we can't design an app for you with so little information. If you really, really can't break up the workload into small units (of 50ms or less) then yes, you'll have to push it into a thread to keep the main loop to be responsive. But, even in that case, do consider using two processes rather than two threads unless you explicitly require completely shared state.

Comment: @NicholasWilson sorry I am not giving more detail, I wasn't looking for a straight up solution just some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to maintain internal state that all threads need access to, you need synchronization. Every thread comes with its own stack, but they all share the heap. If you access an object on the thread, you need to make sure your thread obtains a lock on that state (possibly wait until you can get it) and then changes the state, releases the lock and so on.

The common way to do this on POSIX systems is the [pthread API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). C11 has added standardized threading support to the language which can be found in the header `threads.h`, but support for it is very rare.

Alternatively, you can also use multiple processes. That would change how you communicate between threads but the general model of your application would remain the same.